# Removing Cyrillic text from MySQL Select string

Tags: mysql

Recently i stuck with some problems with MySQL queries. I have table that contains multiple language records. For example Columns are ID and Description. It have data like this 1 test with Кирилица; 2 Test without Cyrillic. I need to remove all cyrillic symbols from Select query. The Select answer must be like 1 test with;2 Test without Cyrillic. Seems like i need to use Select Replace query, but is it possible to do it much faster way than replace 66 characters in query for Header letters and small letters.
I have tried something like that. But of course this isnt working. Hope for help from MySQL Gurus. Thank You for attention

```
SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, REGEXP "[а-яА-Я]", 1)
FROM Test
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no faster method than

```
SELECT id, REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '[Ѐ-ӿ]+', '') AS title FROM test;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9514e541d2048ca6658e8804ed0f1086)

(`"Ѐ"` and `"ӿ"` are the first and last characters, respectively, of Unicode Cyrillic block. If you go with `[а-яА-Я]`, you can miss Cyrillic letters of languages outside Russian, and even the Russian Ё.)